Partitioning User Activity Data in S3 for Athena - multi-level partitioning
Currently dealing with a common problem of storing user activity logs in S3 which than will be queried by Athena. For this, I defined an event class with a lot of telemetry fields. This is used by various lambdas to write the events to S3.
Problem details:

There are 6 fields of interest for querying events: date, sessionId, userId, campaignId, companyId, eventType
Often, queries will not be date specific. For example, looking at all events for a campaign that may spawn across two years or just a user session that goes over midnight

Questions:

What should each file store? I was thinking a file could be named YYYY-MM-DD---userIdX.json so we would store events for a specific day for a specific user per file.
Does it make sense to create 5 folders/partitions in the S3 bucket (excluding date for now) and then store the file in each aka duplicating it 5 to 6 times?
For date, I'm confused if I should do either of the following options or a combination so trying to understand pros and cons:

    // A and B would be additional partitions to the other 5
    // C and D would be re-organizing the other 5 partitions
    A: bucketName/YYYY/MM/DD/YYYY-MM-DD---userIdX.json
    B: bucketName/YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM-DD---userIdX.json
    C: bucketName/[either sessionId, userId, campaignId, companyId or eventType]/YYYY/MM/DD/YYYY-MM-DD---userIdX.json
    D: bucketName/[either sessionId, userId, campaignId, companyId or eventType]/YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM-DD---userIdX.json
    // I assume I could do a combo of either (A and C) or (B and D)


Is there an advantage in using Hive-style partitioning scheme? So for example created_date=2019-03-07 as a subfolder instead of just 2019-03-07.
Do my files get compressed automatically or does my API need to do that?
What compression algorithm do you recommend? (I heard splitable compression is better)


After further investigations, this is what I'm thinking makes most sense:

Filename: YYYY-MM-DD---userIdX.ndjson.[compression algo extension]
I think it does, it's the only way to optimize queries
Going to opt for A&C
I'll use Hive-style names for directory names (key path names)
I should use an algo and manually compress and dicompress
Still research TODO


For 5&6, decided to use bzip2
